# Can Django Serializers serialize non Django classes/objects

Tags: xml, django, serialization, xmlserializer, django-serializer

I want to XML-serialize an object with custom tags using Django serializes, and starting from the fact that it only make use of objects (Django objects) .. is it possible to pass it custom made non-Django objects, where I specify only the tags needed to be passed.

Is that possible, or I'm asking the wrong question.

Thanks in advance!

**-- Edit --**

As an example of what I think of as an input:

```
class market(object):

    def __init__(self,):
        self.grocery = self.GROCERY
        self.electronics = self.ELECTRONICS

    def GROCERY(self,):

        self.item1 = "banana"
        self.item2 = "tomato"
        self.item3 = "apple"

    def ELECTRONICS(self,):

        self.item1 = "laptop"
        self.item2 = "camera"
        self.item3 = "mobile"
```

Now I want to serialize that object into xml and return it as a response in a webpage, like this (as an example):

```
from django.serializers import serialize

data = serialize("xml", market)
```

and this is the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<market>
  <grocery>
    <item1>banana</item1>
    <item2>toamato</item2>
    <item3>apple</item3>
  </grocery>

  <electronics>
    <item1>laptop</item1>
    <item2>camera</item2>
    <item3>mobile</item3>
  </electronics>
</market>
```

Can django serializer do this (or similar) in an easy time saving way?

Comment: Can you maybe give one example of input object and expected result?

Comment: Hi, an edit has been added to my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, provided you instantiate the class, I'm not sure you want to convert class or object:

```
import inspect
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring


def obj_to_xml(obj):
    elem = Element(obj.__class__.__name__)
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.ismethod):
        if name in obj.__dict__.keys():
            child = Element(name)
            method()
            for gname in method.__code__.co_names: 
                gchild = Element(gname)
                gchild.text = str(obj.__dict__[gname])
                child.append(gchild)

            elem.append(child)

    return elem

market = Market()
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>%s' % tostring(obj_to_xml(market))
```

Comment: Seems to be a nice idea .. I'll start a project on github for that purpose based on your code if you don't mind :)) .. sorry for being late .. was a bit busy.